# li1220 (chargered, 4.2v) battery power control with esp32 (2.7v gpio) using pmos

Tags: power-supply, batteries, switch-mode-power-supply, esp32, pmos

My project has two esp32 modules, one of which is the master and the other controls relays and other "peripherals". Please don't ask "why you need to turn the second esp32 on and off", it will consume no more than 100-150mA + that's not the point of the question.

The question is about the circuit and the resistor ratings, since I'm a student and just starting to get into it all.

The esp32 (slave) will be powered (switched on) for a short period of time by a lir1220 battery.
Does this circuit have the right to exist and if so, are the ratings correct and do I need to change something in it?

[image]

https://www.circuitlab.com/circuit/7z68yxwb8bvr/li1220-esp32-control/

Comment: Hmm, you don't want people to ask why yet you want to know if the "circuit have the right to exist"? How does that work?

Comment: yeah, it's work like "yeap, this circuit is valid, but fix that here" for example, but not "for what you need this circuit". I talking about that.